# Migrating Business Units in Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

Just wondering if there is a way to copy across a business unit and all its elements (data, portfolio etc) to another business unit.

I have heard of Reactor by DEG which is an automated tool that from the sounds of it can achieve this.

However wondering if there is a built in tool or a method that others have used to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to automate a migration of objects and data between accounts, you'll need to build something that utilizes [ExactTarget's SOAP API](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/working_with_soap_web_service_api/) and a staging database or file server.  That's what [DEG's Reactor](http://www.degdigital.com/reactor/) does.

Some things to keep in mind:

1. Objects need to be migrated with their dependencies (e.g. email definitions are dependent on portfolio objects, etc.)
2. There are some object you cannot retrieve or create using the API (e.g. Programs and Automations, Exports, Landing Pages, etc.)
3. There are key API differences between account types (E1.0 & E2.0) that will need to be accommodated
4. You'll need to get creative if you're moving large amounts of data.  It can be done.

Disclosure: I work at DEG.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not one available externally.  There may a [HubExchange](https://hubexchange.exacttarget.com/) application to do it.

I have worked on an internal migration tool, and we did it using SOAP/.NET.

Things you can copy:

1. Content
2. DataExtensions (schema not data, use export/import for that)
3. Query
4. UserInitiatedSends
5. Triggered Sends
6. Data Filters
7. Filter Activities
8. Imports

Things you CANNOT copy

1. Programs
2. File Transfer Activities
3. Microsites w/ associated landing pages.
4. Data Extract Activities.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Portfolio items are actually the easiest to migrate and in my opinion the most essential for future proofing the migration. Without migrating them, your old images will still be served by ET... that is... until your old account or BU gets turned off / deleted. Your images will magically break and you won't know why without digging through your email and content area code and comparing URLs.

Disclosure : I also work at DEG and one of the developers of Reactor.

Comment: Good to know.  I will modify my answer.