# Migrating content from one MID to another

Tags: soap-api

I am wondering if the soap API can be used to migrate all email campaigns/content from one MID to another?  I know that I can set up everything that I need for a campaign via the API, just not sure about exporting/retrieving it from the source MID.  Has anyone ever tried this, and if so, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done, but not solely with the API.  Some SFMC objects are not accessible via API.  More details in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57645/5202) post.