# How to export multiple HTML emails(entirely) with all properties(such as Images) from one Exact Target instance to another

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export, automationstudio

I'm trying to find a solution as to migrate all of my HTML emails with their properties i.e. Jpeg/PNG files in them from one instance of Exact Target to another instance , considering these are to separate accounts.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the API, but it's a considerable investment.

SFMC attempted to build their own migration tool, but now outsources it to Marketing Cloud Partners that have built API-based tools to do it.

It was previously discussed in [**this post**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/57549/5202).

Comment: Please also note that most of these APIs are also based around the classic editor for emails and not content builder, so if you have been utilizing Content Builder, you may be SOL.  In a future release (supposedly later this year) they will include more Content Builder API capabilities, but have no details on what or if REST only or include SOAP as well.

Comment: The Content Builder Asset Objects are retrieveable via REST API.  I've used them for an inventory, but not for recreating anything.

Comment: Unfortunately most of these partners dont have a thorough solution, unsuccessful in migrating all the data, and mostly missing basic assets such as images/ampscripts/...

Comment: We have tools to migrate the majority of assets and data.  Like, I said, it's possible, but it's a considerable time and resource investment to build tools to do this work.  The SFMC APIs are a limitation that's preventing a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

After 1 year not sure if is useful but what I have used to move html content and AMPScript emails and images and data extensions into a different business unit (from dev one to a Production one) is this library:

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP

I have used it with classic content