# Transfer Email Templates and content from one Exact target to another (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, content-builder, data-migration

A client migrating from Exatcttarget 1.0 to 2.0.

We have 400+ email templates to transfer.

What's the preferred way to achieve this while keeping the native capability of drag&drop to edit emails?

- Content Builder API?
- 3rd party app?
- Or maybe support can do it?

This was discussed 3.5 years ago here:
[How to export multiple HTML emails(entirely) with all properties(such as Images) from one Exact Target instance to another](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166580/how-to-export-multiple-html-emailsentirely-with-all-propertiessuch-as-images)

What's new since?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a lot has changed. You can get a fair bit done with the REST API, but it's still non-trivial. An email has a lot of dependencies, like images, referenced content blocks, dynamic content, scripting, a source template, landing page links... If you have an old E1.0 account, I guess you're probably wanting to port Classic Content, as well as Content Builder stuff?

Comment: Usually it is recommended to get a Partner or SF Services to do it for you as they have tools and scripts built to handle this and can make sure to watch for gotchas and best practices. Both are going to be $$$$ though.

Comment: @Macca, we don't have access yet to the old E1.0... assuming they only have Classic Content or assuming only Content Builder - would the approach/method be different?

Comment: @Gortonington, thanks for your reply. Could you give an example of one or two "gotchas" or any tools you mention? My understanding is that no Partner neither Salesforce have figured out a clean and robust way to do this, or else a 3rd party tool would have been commercialized already!

Comment: Each bu is generally unique so there is no 'one size fits all option'. But most partners have tools  (think 'helpers') that greatly reduced the LOE on the tasks and have used them multiple times already on multiple accounts, making it fairly tried and true. Example gotcha can be things like ensuring image urls in existing emails from classic being moved to CB are adjusted to match the new CB version hosted in new BU instead of still referencing old BU. Or a million other tiny little considerations to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Im late here, as per recent release from Marketing Cloud. We have package manager which is enabled for the MC administrator role to copy and export the content assets, data extensions, configired journeys and attribute groups to multiple child business units or difference Marketing Cloud Instance.

Comment: For anyone seeing this in the future: Here is a link to the Package Manager documentation, released April 2021: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_pm_supported_objects.htm&type=5 This is available under the Marketing Cloud Apps > Platform > Package Manager.